# TypeError: Cannot read property 'speak' of null, js engine: hermes -Text-to-Speech

Tags: react-native, text-to-speech

I created the React native app and tried to test using a development build. In one of screen I needed to text-to-speech convertor. I run npm
`npm install react-native-tts --save`
and also set the permissions as well. But when I am calling the function like this

```
import Tts from 'react-native-tts';

// Initialize TTS (usually in your component's constructor or componentDidMount)
Tts.setDefaultRate(0.5); // Set speech rate (optional)
Tts.setDefaultPitch(1.0); // Set pitch (optional)

// Function to speak a word or text
const speakText = (text) => {
  Tts.speak(text)
    .then(() => console.log(`Successfully spoken: ${text}`))
    .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
};

// Example usage in a component
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Speak" onPress={() => speakText('Hello, world!')} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

It gives this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'speak' of null, js engine: hermes` 
what is the reason for that?